# retrieve public info from twitter throug api

Tags: twitter

can anyone give me an example of how to retrieve twitter public information, not related to an account, let say, with PHP or javascript or Net???

I know there is a Twitter API & I'm looking at it to get familiarized with, but I need an example quickly, let say for tomorrow, on how to retrieve public/not-account-related info about twitter posts. In example, would I be able to do something like:

`var twitter = new Twitter();

    var theWord = "tsunami";

    var select = " SELECT PostUser, PostDate, PostSubject";

    var from = " FROM PublicTwitts";

    var where = " WHERE Subject/Content LIKE '%" + theWord + "%'";

    var query = select + from + where;

    var culture = "spanish";

    twitter.getJSON(query, spanish);`

Is that possible???

I would be happy with the closest example, while I continue digging into the API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use the [Search API](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search).